# How to change/redirect multiple query string URL to simple one?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are some URLs with the same URL structure pattern:

```
//www.example.com/index.php?hop=this&step=that&fgh=1001
//www.example.com/index.php?hop=this&step=that&fgh=1002
//www.example.com/index.php?hop=this&step=that&fgh=1003
```

The `//www.example.com/index.php?hop=this&step=that&fgh=` part is the same.
`1001~1003` is the only unique part.

I want to change/redirect them to:

```
http://www.example.com/fgh/1001
http://www.example.com/fgh/1002
http://www.example.com/fgh/1003
```

This site runs on Apache with mod_rewrite.
I have tried working on the `.htaccess` file to rewrite the rule, but failed so far.

I hope anyone can help me to rewrite the code in `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?hop=this&step=that&fgh=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /fgh/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^fgh/(\d+)/?$ index.php?hop=this&step=that&fgh=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Keep these 2 rules just below `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: I masked the url but "http://www.example.asia/index.php?hop=this&step=that&fgh=806".  If you need real URL", I need send it by text message or emal.

Comment: There actually another rules in my htaccess file but I am not sure which effect what.  I will post part of my htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you again. When i delete "RewriteRule index\.php - [L]" above in my .htaccess, redirect works, but page generate 404 error. I just wanted to change only URL, but contents.

Comment: Yes I see [link](http://www.example.com/fgh/1001) in browser now, but the page generate 404 error.

Comment: Yes it's joomla. I am not sure I can update .htaccess to latest, I am using too old version.

Comment: Sorry for not saying about cms. Is there no way of internal rewriting in joomla?

Comment: It is actually Joomla framework that has issues with internal rewrite rules.

Comment: hmmm,sad. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you. I dint check it out.
Put it in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hop=(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^step=(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule index/fgh/(.*)/ index.php?fgh=$3
RewriteRule index/fgh/(.*) index.php?fgh=$3
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add main part of my .htaccess file;

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule index\.php - [L]


#This is the code I tried but not working
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hop=this&step=that&fgh=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /fgh/%1? [R=301,L,NC]


## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```